# How to get the position from classname onclick?

Tags: javascript, onclick, label, getelementsbyclassname

I want to get the position of an  label on a click event. For exameple:

```
<label class="labelClass" onclick="getPosition()"> label1 </label>//return position 1
<label class="labelClass" onclick="getPosition()"> label2 </label>//return position 2
<label class="labelClass" onclick="getPosition()"> label3 </label>//return position 3 ...etc
<label class="labelClass" onclick="getPosition()"> label4 </label>
<label class="labelClass" onclick="getPosition()"> label5 </label>
```

```js
function getPosition() {
    //pseudocode to get position
    var label = document.getElementsByClassName("labelClass");
    alert(label.position) //something like this;
}
```

Comment: pass `this` object on function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the `HTMLCollection` to an `Array` so that you can find the index of the element from the list. Hope this works for you..

```
    <label class="labelClass" onclick="getPosition(this)" > label1 </label>//return position 0
    <label class="labelClass" onclick="getPosition(this)" > label2 </label>//return position 1
    <label class="labelClass" onclick="getPosition(this)" > label3 </label>//return position 2 ...etc
    <label class="labelClass" onclick="getPosition(this)"> label4 </label>
    <label class="labelClass" onclick="getPosition(this)"> label5 </label>

    function getPosition(label)
    {
       var list=document.getElementsByClassName("labelClass");
       list = [].slice.call(list); 

       alert(list.indexOf(label));
    }
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkg9fts9/)

Comment: Yes, i checked in a clean file and works...I reviewed my html file and had and logical bug. Now it´s work fine. Thanks and kisses

Answer (score 0):

try this:

- change onclick="getPosition()" to onclick="getPosition(this)"
- in function getPosition:

  -- change function getPosition() to function getPosition(obj)

  -- use `alert(obj.style.position)`

Comment: Show alert in black , but might works in a clean file. In my html file doesn´t work. I review my file for see the reason. Thanks and kisses.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpfull

```
function getPosition()
{
 var p = $(this);
 var position = p.position();
 $( ".result" ).text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );

}
```

Comment: is it jquery? I don´t use it, i am a newbie still :)

Comment: Sir, she is asking the position of a label _in the sequence_ not the position of the element on the screen... though this is may also come handy.

Comment: Yes Gideon, that was my question, but i like thanks for the answer Zohaib Waqar